# Name of UI element

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

i would like to know, what is name of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXutc.png) UI element? The top bar containing "close" or "minimize" buttons?

And is there any way, how to customise it using XAML or C#?

Thanks
[image: Name of this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called the TitleBar.  Can can customize it but you will have to make your own custom style for the main window..  Check out [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/539f0f4c-4057-4122-b0e5-3a01fbed8ea8/windows-10-wpf-window-with-windowstylenone-and-resizemodecanresize-is-showing-white-bar-on?forum=wpf) link.  Give some direction on how to customize.